# Reactive ggplot2 aes() error

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

I am trying to get a plot to appear within shiny according to reactive data.  There are two items, each of which have the same position data, but different values at that position data.  As a stand alone, I know the following code works.

```
library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
library('ggvis')


horizontal_position <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)
vertical_position <- c(-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
item_no <- 1
item_1 <-data.frame(item_no, horizontal_position, vertical_position, data_val)

data <-item_1
itemchoices <- as.character(unique(data$item_no))

# UI

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
          plotOutput("plot1")
   )
 )
)

#SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(data, aes(horizontal_position, vertical_position)) +
     geom_tile(aes(fill = data_val)) + 
     geom_text(aes(label = data_val),colour="white")
 })
}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

However, when I attempt to make it reactive, I am getting the error "Error : Mapping should be created with `aes() or`aes_()`."  My attempted code is below and any troubleshooting help is much appreciated.

```
# INITIAL SET-UP

#Check packages to use in library
{
 library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
 library('ggplot2')
}

#Data

horizontal_position <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)
vertical_position <- c(-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
item_no <- 1
item_1 <-data.frame(item_no, horizontal_position, vertical_position, data_val)

 data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
 item_no <- 2
 item_2 <-data.frame(item_no, horizontal_position, vertical_position, data_val)

 data <-rbind(item_1, item_2)
 itemchoices <- as.character(unique(data$item_no))

 # UI

 ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
          wellPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "item", label="Select item:", choices = itemchoices, selected = "1", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)
          )
    ),
    column(8,
          plotOutput("plot1")
     )
   )
 ) 

 #SERVER

 server <- function(input, output, session)
 {
 filteredData <- reactive({
     m <- data %>% filter(
       item_no %in% input$item
    )
    m
   })
  vis <- reactive({
    p1 = filteredData() %>%
      ggplot(data, aes(horizontal_position, vertical_position)) +
      geom_tile(aes(fill = data_val)) + 
      geom_text(aes(label = data_val),colour="white")
   })
  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
 }

 #Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage

 shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Where is the reactive piece?  I skimmed through and couldn't find a difference between your first code chunk and your second.

Comment: @aosmith oops, wrong copy/paste.  The post has been revised.

Comment: You are passing your dataset `filterData` in via a pipe but forgot to remove `data` from within `ggplot`.  So you are passing `data` to the `mapping` argument and so are getting the error.

Comment: @aosmith so what should that variable p1 look like then? I tried 


    p1 = filteredData() %>%
      ggplot(aes(horizontal_position, vertical_position)) +
      geom_tile(aes(fill = data_val)) + 
      geom_text(aes(label = data_val),colour="white")
   })

and got the error "Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class mts/ts"

Comment: You are likely trying to use `filter` from package *dplyr*, but you didn't load it so are using `filter` from package *stats*.  The latter works on time series and must output a `ts`/time series class.

Comment: @aosmith ah, yes that was an issue.  Now however it is giving an error "Error in UseMethod("as.vega", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'as.vega' applied to an object of class "c('gg', 'ggplot')"